# How to define a static route in traefik.io

Tags: docker, traefik

I am using traefik in a docker swarm. traefik works fine to route my frontends to the corresponding docker services.

My question is: Is it also possible to add a static route into the traefik.toml file which is just routing a request to a static web server which is outside of my docker-swarm?

For example:

incomming request for "http://www.myweb.com" should be redirected to "http://some.host.de:12345/"

*some.host.de* is not part of my docker network. It's an internet server and I just want traefik to reverse-proxy on port 80.
I can't find an example. But it seems that I need to define a [file] section like this in my traefik.toml file?

```
[file]

# rules
[backends]
  [backends.backendstatic1]
    # ...

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontendstatic1]
  # ...
```

How must this be completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[file]

[backends]

  [backends.backend1]

    [backends.backend1.servers]
      [backends.backend1.servers.server0]
        url = "http://some.host.de:12345"
        # note that you cannot add path in 'url' field

[frontends]

  [frontends.frontend1]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "backend1"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes]
      [frontends.frontend1.routes.route0]
        rule = "Host:www.myweb.com"
```

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/backends/file/

Comment: One important thing for the frontent1 definition was the additional option "passHostHeader = true"

Comment: Can you prevent traefik from sending the IP address of the client to the backend in this setup?